# Fixed width layout breaks in IE()

Tags: html, css, layout

I built a web page based on a fixed-fluid mix width layout as I need it to look consistent across all major browsers and on widescreens as well normal ones.
It came out nicely in Fire-Fox and chrome but completely breaks down in IE.

I have a menu with horizontal list items which when hovered have vertical elements, You won't believe it but IE will not show the vertical elements itself

I am just overwhelmed by the difference. here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/thedarkjedi/wknmn/

any idea why my almost half of the CSS dedicated to Menu just stopped working? it works fine in other browsers.

it just breaks down in IE and I mean it. I can not understand where am I making a mistake.

PS: Also can anyone tell me why my footer has a gap b/w itself and bottom (It should stick to the bottom of the page but in the mean time should give place to content if there is more) even after trying almost every trick found in the net.

my code related to footer is:

```
<div id="FooterContainer">

 <div id="Footer" >

    <div id="Footer_Content">
    <ul id="Footer_Nav">

            <li id="Contact"><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
            <li id="About"><a href="#">About</a></li>    
            <li id="ToC"><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>    

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="notice">
            Designed & Developed by Sudhanshu Nautiyal
    </div>

 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
```

and CSS is:

/* Footer begins */

```
#FooterContainer {

    //clear:both;
    background: #b8e1fe;

}

#Footer {


    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0px auto;

}

#Footer_Content {


    text-align:center;  
}

/* Footer Navigation begins*/

#Footer_Nav {

    display: inline-block;
    //width: 100%;

    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

}
#Footer_Nav  li {

    float:left;
}

#Footer_Nav li a {

    //display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #0b6998;
}
/*Footer NAvigation Ends */
```

Answer (score 0):

The double slash (`// comment here`) is not a valid token for comments in CSS, only the full C-style comment block is (`/* comment here */`).  There are other validation errors as well (such as defining widths of elements without specifying a unit `10` vs `10px`).